# netcat is timing out before timeout has reached

Tags: debian, tcp, nc

I am trying to test a port on a remote machine. The connection is over satellite, so latency is quite high. I am testing with NC with the -w option to set the timeout. Ex: `nc -w 300 address port` shouldn't timeout before 300 seconds but it times out in roughly 21 seconds...  Is there any simple way of testing the ports with a longer timeout?  I noticed if I pick a timeout of less than 21 seconds it times out in the time specified.

output of `nc -w 300 address port` is:

```
(UNKNOWN) [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] 6169 (?) : Connection timed out
```

Comment: might not be the netcat timeout timing out.  You should show us the command and the exact response.  May not be helpful, but might be.

Comment: Also: is it a linux system? What kernel version and what glibc ?